# Modify flags while launching from chromedriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using webdriver(http://webdriver.io/) , standalone selenium, mocha to write my test cases. Test cases are specific to chrome so I am using chromedriver.

While launching I want "touch-events" and "touch-optimized-ui" flags to be disabled, else my test cases will fail.

Everytime chromedriver launches the browser, it starts with default options.
Could anybody provide me a solution for this? What can be added to code below to disable those flags? Or maybe some other solution?

Sample Code:

```
var webdriverjs = require('./webdriverjs/index'),
    assert      = require('assert');

describe('my webdriverjs tests', function(){

    this.timeout(99999999);
    var client = {};

    before(function(done){
            client = webdriverjs.remote({ desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'chrome'} });
            client.init(done);
    });

    it('sample test',function(done) {
        client
            .url('http://localhost:3030/subset/index')
            .call(done)
    });

    after(function(done) {
        client.end(done);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any chrome flag within your desired capabilities as follows:

```
client = webdriverjs.remote({
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: ['touch-events','touch-optimized-ui']
        }
    }
});
```